# Can't align vertically using "align-items-center" in Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, alignment

I'm new to Bootstrap and React JS and I'm trying to place my app at the center both vertically and horizontally. Currently this app is placed only horizontally and it seems to be attached to the top.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalContextProvider>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-center align-items-center"> // <--- Doens't work
          <div className="col">
            <Header />
            <Main />
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </GlobalContextProvider>
  );
}
```

I have tried different approaches like my-auto, alight-self-center and others but for some reason nothing seems to work. Could you please help with this one (without using custom css)?

Comment: try `text-center` instead of `align-items-center`

Answer (score 0):

align-items-center aligns cols, so you need tu use one col for every chunk of content you want to align, but you shouln't be using cols for header, main and footer tags